# How can I delete N number of rows after N number of rows in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-manipulation, seq

How can I keep the first 56 rows, then delete the next 6 rows, then keep the next 56 rows, then delete the next 6 rows repeatedly? I found some similar answers (like how to delete the Nth row), but not how to keep a pattern like mentioned.

My data is a data frame, 1 through 7910.

And I would like to
Keep rows 1 through 56.
Delete rows 57 through 62.
Keep rows 63 through 118.
Delete rows 119 through 124.
And continue this pattern through all 7910 rows.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using modulo (`%%`) of the row number:

```
df[((seq_len(nrow(df)) - 1L) %% 62L + 1L) <= 56L, ]
```

The same with `dplyr`:

```
df |> 
  filter(((seq_len(nrow(df)) - 1L) %% 62L + 1L) <= 56L)
```